# Volley android Time out issue

Tags: android, android-volley

I have set below retry policy in volley to call webservice.

```
public static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 120000;  
public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 0;  
public static final float DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT =0f;
```

I want 2 mins for timeout and attempt want only for 1 time. So I have set above property.
But problem is that I got error timeout exception within 64 sec instead of 120 sec.

dose anyone has idea why volley not considering 2 min. When I set 60 sec it is working fine.

Comment: I have also same issue..!! Did you find solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

this.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(SOCKET_TIMEOUT, 2, 1.0F));

for more information check flowing link

http://www.techstricks.com/avoid-multiple-requests-when-using-volley/